# How to complete remove div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ecmascript-6

I create a div element with jQuery:

```
$(document.body).append('<div id="test"></div>');
```

and then show message and remove div after 10s

```
$('test').html('SUCCESS!');
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#test').remove();
}, 10000);
```

and then check if div remove complete, console log show message:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if($('#test').length === 0){
      console.log('DIV removed!');
    } else {
      console.log('DIV not removed!!!')
    }
}
```

When I scroll up or down message show "DIV not removed!!!".

Why my div not removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// onload 
$(function(){
  // set height 1000px  on body for support event scroll
  $('body').css('height','1000px');
  
  // append
  $(document.body).append('<div id="test"></div>');
  $('#test').html('SUCCESS!');
  
  // remove in 2s
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#test').remove();
  }, 2000);
  
  // scroll event
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      if($('#test').length === 0){
        console.log('DIV removed!');
      } else {
        console.log('DIV not removed!!!')
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are running your "check" immediately after adding it to the DOM. The "remove" only happens ten seconds in the future.

I've altered your example to demonstrate the two code placement differences. You can click run and observe the behavior.

I've also changed it to 2 seconds from 10 for faster demonstration.

In short, you should run code you want to run after the removal in after the removal line itself.

```js
$(document.body).append('<div id="test"></div>');

$('#test').html('SUCCESS!');
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#test').remove();
  
  // Runs LATER
  if($('#test').length === 0){
    console.log('[LATER] DIV removed!');
  } else {
    console.log('[LATER] DIV not removed!!!')
  }
}, 2000);

// Immediately, Befor setTimeout has run
if($('#test').length === 0){
  console.log('[IMMEDIATE] DIV removed!');
} else {
  console.log('[IMMEDIATE] DIV not removed!!!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want when scroll page show this message